# How can I solve "Type error: Argument 2 passed to ... must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile"?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, upload, laravel-5.3

My controller is like this :

```
public function store(CreateProductRequest $request)
{
    ...
    $result = $this->product_service->createProduct($param,$photo);
    ...
}
```

My service is like this :

```
public function createProduct($param, UploadedFile $photo=null)
{
    dd($photo);
    if($photo) {
        $fileName = str_random(40) . '.' . $photo->guessClientExtension();
        $param['photo'] = $fileName;
        $param['photo_list'] = json_encode(['id'=>1,'name'=>$fileName]);
    }
    ...
    if(is_array($result) && count($result)>1 && $result[0])
        $this->savePhoto($photo, $fileName,$result[1]->id);
    ...
    return $result;
}

private function savePhoto(UploadedFile $photo, $fileName, $id)
{
    $destinationPath = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'products'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$id;
    $photo->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    resize_image($fileName,250,'products',$id);
    return $fileName;
}
```

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile is like this : https://pastebin.com/KLfnXZJV

When variable `$photo` Not an array or just 1 data, I do `dd($photo);`, it display the result

But when variable `$photo` is array, I do `dd($photo);`, there exist error :

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to
>   App\Services\ProductService::createProduct() must be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, array given

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is `$photo` being defined? You have the `createProduct` method type hinted so that the parameter *MUST* be an instance of `UploadedFile`.

Comment: @Jeremy Harris, It defined in controller. If `$photo` like this : https://postimg.org/image/47t72locf/, no error. But `$photo` like this : https://postimg.org/image/58qo0i8u7/, there exist error

Comment: As Jeremy sais, it must be an UploadedFile Instance. Could you provide us more controller code?

Comment: I think you are trying to do a multi-upload? If so, then in your controller, you need to loop over that array of photos, and for each one of them, call `product_service->createProduct(..., ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are either getting a single file, or an array of files. Does creating a product support uploading more than one file? If not, you can do something like this:

```
// If file is inside an array, pull it out
if (is_array($photo) && $photo[0] instanceof UploadedFile) {
    $photo = $photo[0];
}

// Run upload
$result = $this->product_service->createProduct($param, $photo);
```

If you require the ability to upload multiple files, a few things would need to happen. First, you can't typehint your method as `UploadedFile`. Instead, typehint it as an array:

```
public function createProduct($param, array $photos = [])
```

And then in your `createProduct` logic, you will need to loop through the array of photos and save them individually.

Finally, in your controller, you will need to do the opposite of the first suggestion and instead of extracting *from* an array, you need to put it in one:

```
if ($photo instanceof UploadedFile) {
    $photo = [$photo];
}
```